# How would I submit my form data in a proper way by mailing in a simple HTML website?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tried to get this type of mail from my HTML website.

**Name:** XYZ

**Email:** xyz@gmail.com

**Message:** msg

Can anybody help me to get this type of mail when somebody fills my HTML form, Remember I don't want to use any programming language like PHP. If anyone has javascript code for it then please share it.

Comment: Without server side code, the only thing you can do is to open up the email program of the user with this data. But this is not a good user experience and is therefore discouraged

Comment: Stackoverflow is not code sharing site... if you are stuck in any stage of  coding,you can share your code here and we can solve it, show me your code

Comment: "*I don't want to use any programming language*" What's the reason for this requirement? As @DanielHilgarth has pointed out, the only way to do this would be a `mailto:`, which is traditionally considered awful UX.

Comment: JavaScript *is* a programming language. You need some server-side code to make this work in a remotely reliable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mailto attribute to your form in the action attribute

So it would look like this on your form element

```
<form action="mailto:name@example.com" method="POST" ...>
```

And in javascript you would use preventDefault to stop it submitting straight away so you can validate and sanitise any inputs before the form is submitted

ETA: Like Daniel Hilgarth said, it's not good practice to do this and server side scripting would be much better

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Of course, my pleasure!

Comment: This isn't just "not good practice", it is [highly unreliable and often just won't work](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)